# How do I convert from int64 back to timestamp or datetime'?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I am working on a project to look at how much a pitcher's different pitches break each game. I looked here for an earlier error which fixed my error but it gives me some weird numbers. What I mean is like when I print what I hope to be August 3rd,2020 I get 1.5964128e+18. Here's how I got there.

```
hughes2020=pd.read_csv(r"C:/Users/Stratus/Downloads/Hughes2020Test.csv",parse_dates=['game_date'])
game=hughes2020['game_date'].astype(np.int64)
#Skipping to next part to an example
elif name[i]=="Curveball":
   if (c<curve)
      xcurve[c]=totalx[i]
      ycurve[c]=totaly[i]
      cudate[c]=game[i]
      c+=1
```

and when I print the cudate it gives me the large number and I am wondering how I can change it back.

And if I run it as

```
game=hughes2020['game_date'] #.astype(np.int64)
    #Skipping to next part to an example
    elif name[i]=="Curveball":
       if (c<curve)
          xcurve[c]=totalx[i]
          ycurve[c]=totaly[i]
          cudate[c]=game[i]
          c+=1
```

It gives me an

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'

Comment: Why are you reading it in the int64 format in the first place ? I would assume they are stored as Epochs, which would be a long

Answer (score 1):

To convert `int` to `datetime` use `pd.to_datetime()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[1.5964128e+18], columns = ['t'])
df['t2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t'])

              t         t2
0  1.596413e+18 2020-08-03
```

However a better solution would be to convert the dates at the time of csv reading (As @sinanspd correctly pointed out). Use `parse_dates` and other related options in `pd.read_csv()`. Function manual is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: I used parse_dates at the first line given. But without the conversion to int it would give me this error: 
''' 'TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp' '''

Comment: For now just use `to_datetime` as in my answer (pls accept).

But where exactly do you get this TypeError? Could you give a bigger example?

Comment: Like if I removed the to int like

'game=hughes2020['game_date'] #.astype(N.int64)/10**9'
then it gives me the error